# Смена расположения div`ов в row при ресайзе

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

При FHD расположение блоков идет в ряд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При малых разрешения выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно поменять местами, как показано стрелкой. `col-push-*` `col-pull-*` не помогают

Исходник:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row news_block">
            <div class="news_logo col-lg-1 col-md-1">

            </div>
            <div class="news_content col-lg-7 col-md-12">

            </div>
            <div class="news_date col-lg-2 col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Предоставьте хоть минимальный код с проблемой, иначе вам вряд-ли кто-то поможет!

Comment: Извиняюсь, недавно здесь. Отредактировать вопрос нельзя уже?

Comment: @Atomrr, можно, под вашим вопросом есть ссылка "править"

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row news_block">
    <div class="news_content col-lg-7 col-lg-push-1 col-md-12">
      block 2
    </div>
    <div class="news_logo col-lg-1 col-lg-pull-7 col-md-1">
      block 1
    </div>
    <div class="news_date col-lg-2 col-md-3">
      block 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .news_block{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .news_block  .news_content{
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row news_block">
    <div class="news_logo col-lg-1 col-md-1">
      block 1
    </div>
    <div class="news_content col-lg-7 col-md-12">
      block 2
    </div>
    <div class="news_date col-lg-2 col-md-3">
      block 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а без свой свойства display: table это не решить? Нужно оставить блочной моделью, таблицу нельзя :\

Comment: Почему нельзя? Просто интересно откуда такой бред берется.

Comment: @Atomrr Обновил ответ

Comment: @xaja от работодателя :\ таблицей конечно было бы это все проще сделать

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, не додумался бы изначально поменять местами)

Comment: Работодатели совсем умнее пошли... диктуют, что и как нужно делать, совсем не понимая зачем это нужно.

Comment: @Atomrr Работодатель будет смотреть css на наличие `display:table-cell`?

Comment: @xaja бекэнд прогер смотрит, он и сказал, что нельзя

Comment: бекэнд(!) прогер(!!) говорит что нельзя `table-cell`(!!!). Бегите!

Comment: @Atomrr - А какое отношение имеет бекэнд к table (table-cell) ?

Comment: @xaja я бы с радостью, но это моя первая работа, так что остаюсь, пока не подтяну знания)

Comment: @soledar10 честно, я не знаю, но пришлось это сделать